# Internal error in SSAS when I try process one dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, ssas-2008

So, I working with SQL Server and now I have a problem to process a dimension.
Someone knows how I can fix this problem?

I try search in internet but what I found was just this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970538

For you know, the configurations are: SQL Server 2008 R2 with Visual Studio 2008.

I not create anything new, I just put to process the dimension and happened this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting isn't exactly the one quoted on the Microsoft support page.  So I guess the problem is not the one described there.

That doesn't leave much certainty, except that *something* has gone wrong with the storage of the dimension.  What [kind of processing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774.aspx) are you attempting?  Is it practicable to do a ProcessClear and then ProcessFull on the dimension?  (Note that this will require all partitions that depend on the dimension to be reprocessed as well).

In answer to your **comment**:
That is strange.  All I could guess is that the cube process is deciding for some reason that the part of the dimension that is causing the problem doesn't need to be reprocessed.  I guess a radical solution would be to back up your project files, delete the dimension (and obviously any dependencies), deploy the project.  Then go back to your backed up project and deploy that, creating the dimension again from nothing.

A less radical approach might be to deliberately change the dimension, perhaps by adding a (nonsense) attribute at leaf level.  Deploy and process, then change back.  The idea is to try to destroy and recreate the stored data that is causing this problem.

Comment: Yes, is possible, but I always process in ProcessFull, to process the object and all the objects that it contains.
And more strange, if I process a cube that contain this dimension, it's work. Is just in particular this dimension.